# How to pass a HashMap as side input in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to pass a HashMap as side input in a Dataflow pipeline.  I can't find any examples except the few that pass either String, Int or Long.  My code:

```java
tagList = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("tagListTextRead").from("gs://mybucket/tag-list.json"));

PCollection<Map<String,TagObject>> tagMap = tagList
            .apply(ParDo.named("allTagsToTagMap").of(new Tags.BuildTagListMapFn()));


PCollectionView<Map<String, TagObject>> tagMapView =
            allTags.apply(View.<String, TagObject>asMap());
```

The 3rd statement gives a syntax error.

```java
The method apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<Map<String,TagObject>>,OutputT>) in the type 
     PCollection<Map<String,TagObject>> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (View.AsMap<String,TagObject>)
```

Can someone show me how to pass a HashMap as side input in a Dataflow pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two different answers, depending on the details of your pipeline.

1. If you have a `PCollection<KV<K, V>>` then you can use `View.asMap()` to produce a `PCollectionView<Map<K, V>>`. There is no need to build the `Map` yourself.
2. If you have a `PCollection<Map<K, V>>` with a single element then you can use `View.asSingleton()` to side input.

The first is probably the most natural, and your code will end up looking like

```java
PCollectionView<Map<String, TagObject>> = pipeline
    .apply("tagListTextRead", TextIO.Read.from("gs://mybucket/tag-list.json"))
    .apply("tagsToKv", new Tags.TagToKvFunction())
    .apply("viewTags", View.<String, TagObject>asMap())
```

Expanding this to show the types of the intermediate values:

```java
PCollection<String> rawTags =
    pipeline.apply("tagListTextRead", TextIO.Read.from("gs://mybucket/tag-list.json"))

PCollection<KV<String, TagObject>> kvs =
    rawTags.apply("tagsToKv", new Tags.TagToKvFunction())

PCollectionView<Map<String, TagObject>> =
    kvs.apply("viewTags", View.<String, TagObject>asMap())
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  This worked out for me.  My case was #2 so using asSingleton was what I needed.